# Apex trigger zero code coverage

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, test-class, apex-trigger

Can anyone please help me to solve my issue.
I have created apex trigger with test classes.
I am not getting any error after test run but unable to getting any code coverage.
Please check below is my apex trigger and test class.

```
                trigger getAllContacts on Scheme__c (after insert,after update) 
            {
                List<ANZSIC_Contact__c> acc = new List<ANZSIC_Contact__c>();
                for(Scheme__c scheme :trigger.new)
                {
                    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Underwriter').getRecordTypeId();
                    if(scheme.Account__c != null && scheme.Account__r.RecordTypeId== devRecordTypeId )
                    {
                        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
                        con = [select Id,Email,Phone from contact where Account.Id =:scheme.Account__c];
                        for(Contact c:con)
                        {
                            acc = [select Id from ANZSIC_Contact__c where Contact__c =:c.Id and Scheme__c =:scheme.Id];
                            if(acc ==Null)
                            {
                                ANZSIC_Contact__c ac = new ANZSIC_Contact__c();
                                ac.Contact__c = c.Id;
                                ac.Scheme__c = scheme.Id;
                                ac.Email__c = c.Email;
                                ac.Phone__c = c.Phone;
                                acc.add(ac);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        insert acc;
                    }
                }
            }

            @isTest(seeAllData=false)
            private class Test_getAllContacts
            {
                static testMethod void getAllContacts()
                {
                    test.startTest();
                    RecordType businessAccountRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND Name = 'Underwriter'];
                    Account acc = new Account();
                    acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                    acc.RecordTypeId = businessAccountRecordType.Id;
                    insert acc;Contact con = new Contact();
                    con.LastName = 'Test data';
                    con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                    con.Email ='n@yahoo.in';
                    con.Phone = '987654321';
                    insert con; Scheme__c  sh = new Scheme__c();
                    sh.Account__c = acc.Id; 
                      test.stopTest();
                }
            }
```

Comment: no code? attest the necessary apex trigger and test class

Comment: Unable to upload code here.

Comment: copy, paste the code

Comment: It gives me error code not formatted as a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am a bit late to answer, but ...

`@isTest(seeAllData=false)` : Your query will not fetch you the record type information in your test class if you set the seeAllData to false!

Either set it to true or if it is not permitted, create a recordtype record/data in your test class.